# How to see array's all member?

Tags: php, mysql

I keep, times of a load money in the `balance_times` variable in the database, and when I load money I keep that time in `balance_time` . Please be carriful for the name. 
I want to keep time, in the  `$column` array when I try this code blocks this give me just : `Array ( [10] => 2019-06-08 01:44:27 )`

But I want to show all time in the array. I am seeing just last time. How can I do this ? Where is my fault ?

```
$results = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT balance_times FROM users WHERE user_idx= '$id'");
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
$balance_t= $row['balance_times'];
}
    $column = array();    
    $sql3="UPDATE users SET balance_times=balance_times+1 WHERE user_idx='$id';";
                    mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);
                   $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT balance_time FROM users WHERE user_idx= '$id'");

                   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                  $column[$balance_t] = $row['balance_time'];

                  }
                 print_r($column);
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Thank you but I want to learn how to solve my question. I just learn how to do this is not website.

Comment: Can you describe the question in more clear words?

Comment: That comes across as "I don't want to learn". This code needs considerable improvement, but the problems aren't that hard to solve. It just requires using the proper technique in a disciplined way to avoid ugly bugs that can cost you huge. It's like how the indentation in this code is pure chaos but would take, at most, a minute to tame. It's little things like that which create a lot of confusion and frustration.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is because you don't explain what the desired outcome is. Explaining what you're seeing is important but we need to know the goal. "All time" meaning what? Can you give some sample output? This table doesn't have any history information in it, there's only one column to represent the `balance_time`. Once changed that's going to erase history.